# Bash remove all lines starting with a string including whitespaces

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to delete a few lines from fstab using sed or awk, i want to delete those lines that are starting with some prefix, those lines might have whites spaces.

I've tried this option: `sed -i '/^SomeFileSystem/d' fstab`
but it's not deleting the line..

fstab entry:

```
myServer:/clearcase /clearcase nfs rw,hard,intr,bg,tcp,vers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,timeo=4
```

This is the command that I'm trying to execute

```
sed -i '/^myServer:/clearcase/d' fstab
```

Comment: If that isn't working then the line doesn't start with `SomeFileSystem`. What does it start with?

Comment: This is my real line in fstab: 
`myServer:/clearcase                /clearcase          nfs   rw,hard,intr,bg,tcp,vers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,timeo=4`
This is the command that i'm trying to execute `sed -i '/^myServer:/clearcase/d' fstab`

Comment: You can't stick a slash in the `//` address like that. Escape it. You failed to tell us that it *was* changing the line just not deleting it. That's a detail, like the actual contents (or something equally representative) that is *vital*.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not working because of the slash `/` in the string you are looking for.

Just use another `sed` separator:

```
sed -i '\@^myServer:/clearcase@d' fstab
```

Comment: You need to escape the leading `@` for alternate delimiter in addresses.

Comment: what about the whitespaces in the line?

Comment: ops I noticed it does not work like this, so better to escape `/`

Comment: @user3502786 better update your question. Where are these spaces/

Comment: @user3502786 sed doesn't care about anything you aren't matching.

Comment: @user3502786 by the way, remember you can always accept an answer if your issue is solved

Answer (score 0):

Escape the slash inside:

```
myServer:/clearcase /clearcase nfs rw,hard,intr,bg,tcp,vers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,timeo=4
```

Try this:

```
sed -i '/^myServer:\/clearcase/d' fstab
```

Answer (score 0):

If the line may start with whitespace, adapt your regex to say so.

```
sed -i '\#^ *myserver:/clearcase#d' fstab
```

This also avoids the requirement to escape the slash by using a different regex delimiter than slash.